# Series expansion of $\frac{1}{(1-x)^{-n}-1}$

Tags: real-analysis, power-series

Let $f_n(x)=\frac{1}{(1-x)^{-n}-1}$ with a positive integer $n$.  I am interested in upper-bounding this function for small positive values of $x$ in terms of $x$ and $n$.  I don't think that the Taylor series is defined for $f_n(x)$ as $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^+}f_n(x)=\infty$.  However, when I ran the <kbd>Series</kbd> command on this function in Wolfram Mathematica, I got the following output:

```
In[1]:= Series[((1 - x)^(-n) - 1)^(-1), {x, 0, 2}]
Out[1]:= 1/(n x)+(-(1/2)-1/(2 n))+((-1+n^2) x)/(12 n)+((-1+n^2) x^2)/(24 n)+O[x]^3
```

So Mathematica tells me that the series expansion of $f_n(x)$ is as follows:

$$f_n(x)=\frac{1}{nx}-\frac{1}{2}\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)+\frac{(n^2-1)x}{12n}+\frac{(n^2-1)x^2}{24n}+\mathcal{O}(x^3)$$

The first term in this expansion gave me an idea for the upper bound that I needed, as $f_n(x)\leq\frac{1}{nx}$.  I can easily prove that it holds for positive $n$ and small positive $x$ using the binomial expansion of $(1-x)^{-n}=1+nx+\frac{1}{2}(n+n^2)x^2+\mathcal{O}(x^3)\geq 1+nx\Rightarrow \frac{1}{nx}\geq\frac{1}{(1-x)^{-n}-1}$.

My questions are: what kind of series expansion did Mathematica give me and is there an equivalent of Taylor's Theorem with the remainder for it?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymptotic_expansion

Comment: It gave you a Laurent expansion at the origin. Notice that the function has a pole there.

Comment: Hmm...  I didn't know about Laurent series... thanks!